# How to display exit code in WSL?

Tags: c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have to write certain functions in C that gives back values. My teacher uses the 'return' function but i don't know how to display this exit code in WSL. I know that in certain IDE the exit code is diplayed when running a program. Is this posible to do the same in WSL ?

Is there a certain command to type when running the code (sort of a -Wall or -O3) or something else ?

Comment: Google this in the context of `bash`, it doesn't matter if you use WSL or not. If you use `./a.out` to run the program, then `./a.out; echo Exit code: $?` would print the exit code after it finishes executing.

Comment: ... and this is not directly related to C.  In the context you're talking about, it is a behavior of the *shell* (often, but not necessarily `bash`) that accepts and executes your interactive commands.  The same applies to programs written in other languages.

Comment: This is not related to C.  Anyway, you should show your code.  If you don't show any code, no help is possible, as no diagnostic can be made.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  for an explanation on how to post a problem to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$?` to check whether your code has exited.

```
//...
status=$?
echo $status
```

Comment: And it is often important to capture the value in `$?` because it changes when new commands (e.g. `echo`) are run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I think this is what Doflinwu does with `status=$?`, don't you agree?

Comment: @LuisColorado — yes, he does; I'm just emphasizing the importance of doing so.  The value of `$?` is volatile: `(exit 1); echo $?; echo $?` echoes `1` and `0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Agree!  Good!